# Ao adicionar utente, dá sempre ERRO mas acaba por adicionar

Tags: php, mysql

Boas galera, estou com um problema que é o seguinte: num formulário para adicionar o utente eu preencho tudo e adiciona o utente porém aparece a mensagem a dizer:

> ERRO:"Tente Novamente".

Como é que é possível ele adicionar o utente mas mostrar uma mensagem de erro. Deixo aqui o código `php` com ligação ao `mysql`:

```
    <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$nomeutente=$_POST['NomeUtente'];
$pessoaref=$_POST['PessoaRef']; 
$responsavel=$_POST['Responsavel'];   
$nrutente=$_POST['NrUtente']; 
$telemovel=$_POST['TelemovelContact'];  
$telefone=$_POST['TelefoneContact'];  
$datanascimento=$_POST['DataNascimento'];  
$nridcivil=$_POST['NrIdCivil'];  
$nacionalidadeutente=$_POST['NacionalidadeUten'];  
$nrsaude=$_POST['NrUtenSaude']; 
$sql="INSERT INTO tblutentes(NomeUtente, PessoaRef, Responsavel, NrUtente, TelemovelContact, TelefoneContact, DataNascimento,NrIdCivil, NacionalidadeUten, NrUtenSaude) VALUES(:nomeutente, :pessoaref ,:responsavel, :nrutente, :telemovel, :telefone, :datanascimento, :nridcivil, :nacionalidadeutente, :nrsaude)";
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':nomeutente',$nomeutente,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':pessoaref',$pessoaref,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':responsavel',$responsavel,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':nrutente',$nrutente,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':telemovel',$telemovel,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':telefone',$telefone,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':datanascimento',$datanascimento,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':nridcivil',$nridcivil,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':nacionalidadeutente',$nacionalidadeutente,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':nrsaude',$nrsaude,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$query->execute();

if($lastInsertId)
{
$msg="Utente Adicionado Com Sucesso!";
}
else 
{
$error="Erro, tente novamente!";
}}
?>
```

Comment: Qual o retorno do mysql para a execução do código acima? O erro, tente novamente é a sua mensagem tratada. Edita o post e coloca o retorno do mysql para podermos auxiliar mais facilmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa inverter a ordem, pois se ainda não executou a query, não teve alterações.

Também, poderá precisar do `commit` dependendo de como está usando.

Exemplo:

```
...
$query->execute();
$lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
$dbh->commit(); # caso necessário
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado :)

Comment: pode por favor ver se me consegue ajudar nesta outra questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328318/n%C3%A3o-grava-dados-com-mysql